# Show that $(a_{n})^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is bounded iff $(b_{n})^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, bounded-variation

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Show that if $(a_{n})^{\infty}_{n=1}$ and $(b_{n})^{\infty}_{n=1}$ are eventually $\epsilon$-close, then $(a_{n})^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is bounded iff $(b_{n})^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is bounded.

**MY ATTEMPT**

If $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are eventually $\epsilon$-close, then there exists a natural number $N\geq 0$ such that $|a_{n} - b_{n}| \leq \epsilon$ for every $n\geq N$. If $a_{n}$ is bounded, one has that $|a_{n}| \leq M$. Consequently, we have that
\begin{align*}
|b_{n}| \leq |a_{n} - b_{n}| + |a_{n}| \leq \epsilon + M
\end{align*}
for $n\geq N$. If we take $B = \max\{|b_{1}|,|b_{2}|,\ldots,|b_{N-1}|,\epsilon + M\}$, then $|b_{n}|\leq B$ for every natural $n$, and we are done.

Similar reasoning applies to the converse case.

Could someone verify my arguments?

Comment: Yes, that's good. (And as you mention, the converse case follows by symmetry.) The only tiny thing you could add is that "There exists $M\geq 0$ such that [...]" (the symbol $M$ is not defined by the statement).